# How to use routing "user/{id?}/{fn?}"

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

How do I use routing to pass multiple optional parameters in the url ?

```
http://example.com/user
http://example.com/user/22
http://example.com/user/25/disable

Route::resource('users', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));

Route::get('users/{id}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));
Route::post('users/{id}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));

Route::get('users/{id}/{pages}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));
Route::post('users/{id}/{pages}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reverse the routes:

```
Route::get('users/{id}/{pages}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));
Route::post('users/{id}/{pages}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));

Route::get('users/{id}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));
Route::post('users/{id}', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));

Route::resource('users', 'AdminController@users', array('before'=>'auth'));
```

because otherwise "http://example.com/user/25/disable" will hit Route::resource() first, and match with /user first

Comment: I wanted to use something like `Route::resource('user/{id?}/{pages?}', array('before'=>'auth'));` ... to put the different parameters in one line. Is it possible ?

Comment: Your probably better off just defining each route individually - gives you must better control over your application. see this blog: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil